# Truncating url in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Powershell:

Help: I want to truncate this url:

```
https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html
```

into this:

```
 merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful
```

and store it into a variable.

I tried wildcards but wouldn't work. I tried replacing "/" with newline "`n" and tried reading the last line. Also I successfully tried the code below.
The code that i used and worked is:

```
$rightPart="https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html"
$rightPart=$rightPart.Replace(".html","")
while($rightPart -imatch "/"){
$pos = $rightPart.IndexOf("/")
$rightPart = $rightPart.Substring($pos+1)
}
Write-Output "String is: $rightPart"
```

But i want a better way.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing string parsing acrobatics, you can interrogate the URL with the URI  Class in combination with using the FileInfo constructor to get the basename of the document.

```
$url = "https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html"

([IO.FileInfo]([System.Uri]$url).Segments[-1]).BaseName
```

What is nice about this is that it will get the last filename in the URL no matter if it ends with .htm/.html/.asp/.aspx/etc and whether you have one slash "/" or 20.

Another way is to use Split-Path and grab the leaf object in combination with grabbing the BaseName of the FileInfo object.

```
([IO.FileInfo](Split-Path $url -Leaf)).BaseName
```

Comment: That's certainly beautiful. That came out of nowhere, yet so elegant. I never thought it could be done. Now I know it could be done. Thank you for this beautiful tip.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this?

```
$url = 'https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html'
$arr = $url -split '/'
$truncatedVar = ($arr[$arr.Length-1]).Substring(0, $arr[$arr.Length-1].IndexOf('.'))
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. That was definitely shorter code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Else you can do it too : $arr=($url -split '/')[-1] ; $arr=$arr.Substring(0, $arr.IndexOf('.'))

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions with the `-replace` operator.

```
$url = 'https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html'
$truncatedVar = $url -replace ".*/(.*)\.html",'$1'
```

`.*/` matches zero or more of any character up to the last slash

`(.*)\.html` matches zero or more of any character up to the `.html` string. The parenthesis cause all matched text to be captured to a variable.

`'$1'` is the second argument to the `-replace` operator, telling it what to replace the matched text with. In this case `$1` evaluates to the text that was captured by `(.*)`

/edited to fix the double-quotes, also escaped the '.' in `.html`

Comment: i just ran the code. It looks like the whole $url is getting replaced with a null value. $1 seems to contain nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally replaced single-quotes with double-quotes on the '$1' parameter. When in double-quotes, powershell tries to evaluate the $1 variable within the double-quotes, which does, indeed, result in nothing.

Comment: Ok. That solved it. I was still looking for where it went wrong. This format is still so much shorter than all. Thank you.

Comment: Regular expressions are worth learning. Many languages have native support for them.

Comment: I agree. I like the wildcard formatting for the string. Thats very special. Again, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

```
$URL="https://thoudamchitaranjan.blogspot.in/2017/12/merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html"
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($URL)
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely is useful for my other problem when I want to get the file name of a file. However, for the current problem, it returns: "merry-christmas-and-still-merry-shes-still-so-beautiful.html" hence, I ll have to truncate the ".html" in a different statement.

Comment: It works. I really didn't think that IO.Path will allow me to work with urls, but it does work, and its a wonder i guess. Maybe, its because linux uses front-slashes for paths. Its a neat cheat. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Ricc Babbitt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353880/45375):

**PowerShell *Core*** - but, unfortunately, *not Windows PowerShell* - supports **`Split-Path -LeafBase`**, which allows **extraction of the base filename** (the filename without extension) in a single operation:

```
# PowerShell *Core* only
PS> Split-Path -LeafBase "https://example.org/shes-still-so-beautiful.html"
shes-still-so-beautiful
```